# Suitable Meta heuristic optimization approaches to solve the problem

Tags: python, optimization, methods, mathematical-optimization, heuristics

I am new to optimization approaches and I want to practice doing it by applying one of the optimization methods to solve the problems but I didn't have any ideas where to start from. I will explain the problems in the file csv(**A_08.json**) as you can find from here https://gitlab.com/Schrodinger168/practice/-/blob/master/A_08.json :

-For **Ressources** there are for example **Ressources_X** that **X** here can be a value from 1 to 9. All **Ressource_X** have their **min** and **max** values that needed to be respect as the final solution(will say below0 cannot smaller than **min** and bigger than **max** for each day of all the **Ressources_X**.

- For **Seasons** there are **winter**, **summer**, **is**... and each number correspond in those seasons refer to the day for example **winter** defines from day 1 to day 13 and the other seasons mean the same.
- For **Interventions** there are **Intervention_X** with corresponding workload containing **Ressources_X** that they have to use. **Delta** is the duration of the **Intervention_X** for example we can see in **Intervention_625** as the first value(first day) in the **Delta** list is **1.0** it means that if the **Intervention_625** starts at day 1 it needs to finish in the same day because its Delta value for day 1 is **1.0** and so on... Each **Intervention_X** has their own **tmax** for example **Intervention_625** has **tmax** equal to **17** it means that it can be start between day 1 and day 17 as it wants and the other **tmax** of other **Intervention_X** means the same.
- For **Exclusion** there are some exception for example:

**"E141["Intervention_315","Intervention_456","summer"]** It means that **Intervention_315** and **Intervention_456** cannot start at the same day during the summer days and the others mean the same.

- **T** is the total duration here **T = 17** it means that the duration is 17 days
- The solution I want to generate is the name of interventions and the starting day (t1,t2..) of each of those interventions for example:

**Intervention_X t1**

**Intervention_Y t2**

and so on... until all the Interventions have been used as they will use for only one time.

And those solutions will make sure that it respects the conditions of using the **Ressources (min, max) for each day**, **Exclusion**, and the finish date can be **T + 1** for maximum.

Here is my code to access to each nodes and values of csv file if needed:

```
class access_json:

    def __init__(self):
        self._resources = dict()
        self._seasons = dict()
        self._interventions = dict()
        self._exclusions = dict()
        
        self._NRESOURCES = 0
        self._NINTERVENTIONS = 0
        self._list_resources = list()
        self._list_interventions = list()
        
        self._T = 0
        self._senariosNumber = []
        self._quantile = 0
        self._alpha = 0
        
    def loadjson(self, fpath: str):
        js = dict()
        with open(fpath, 'r') as f:
            js = json.load(f)
        
        self._resources = js["Resources"]
        self._NRESOURCES = len(self._resources)
        self._list_resources = list(self._resources.keys())
        self._seasons = js["Seasons"]
        self._interventions = js["Interventions"]
        self._NINTERVENTIONS = len(self._interventions)
        self._list_interventions = list(self._interventions.keys())
        self._exclusions = js["Exclusions"]
        
        self._T = js["T"]
        self._senarios_number = js["Scenarios_number"]
        self._quantile = js["Quantile"]
        self._alpha = js["Alpha"]
```

Any help with codes, recommendation for how to apply the optimizations approaches for this problem would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand what the problem is. E.g. what is an "intervention"? What is a "ressource"? What are we optimizing?

Comment: Intervention is like a task have to be planned and each intervention needs to use ressources in order to start the work.